# Как лучше орагнизовать redux-приложение?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Есть приложение на `react`, в котором используется `redux`  и `react-router`. У приложения есть разные блоки-страницы, например: продукты, результаты. Для каждого из них есть свои сторы. Также есть переключатель, который меняет язык. При смене языка надо делать запрос на `api`  и тогда придут переведенные продукты и др данные. Собственно говоря возникают следующие вопросы. Если пользователь находится на странице продуктов и меняет язык, то нелогично обновлять все сторы подряд(в том числе и стор результатов,которые пока не просматриваются). Та же история с переходом по конкретной ссылке с помощью рутера. Если пользователь зашел на страницу результатов, то надо продиспатчить только те сторы, которые нужны для этой страницы. У меня была мысль создать отдельный модуль, где был бы метод со `swtich-case`'ом . этот метод я думал вызывать в `didMount` компонентов и передаватьв  зависимости от страницы их названия. И после этого через свитч дергать нужные экшны. Но это не работает. Что еще можно придумать, чтобы оптимизировать приложение?

Comment: Я думаю что не нужно делать запрос на обновление сторов. У вас должен быть специальный словарь где ключи это слова на русском языке, а значения слова на иностранном. Вы просто оборачиваете выводимый из сторов текст в специальную функцию которая в зависимости от выбранной локализации показывает (или не показывает) перевод из словаря.
Работать должно по аналогии с функцией gettext в GNU
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext
А вот бибилиотека для реализации похожего функционала на js 
https://messageformat.github.io/Jed/

Comment: Я выносил в redux стор только глобальные данные которые нужны во всём приложении (типа авторизационных данных, роли, и т.п.) А если данные нужны были только на конкретной странице я использовал локальный стейт (то есть только реакт без редакс). Не факт что это правильный подход...

Comment: спасибо за комментарий,но ситуация такова, что надписи интерфейса, который я на реакте пилю, я перевел(как раз с помощью getText). у меня есть стор,который в зависимости от выбранного языка подключает тот,или иной файл с переводами и все хорошо.но есть еще контент,который приходт с апи, вот он как раз переводится на бэкенде.и за переведенным контентом надо делать запрос с нужным языком.в этом вся и соль.не я это придумал и поменять это нельзя. насчет хранения в стейте. ваш подход справедлив в зависимости от данных и от того, что с ними надо сделать. в моем случае лучше хранить в сторах